# Saving a selected document as a response document with XPages

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino

i am new to xpages, but i want to try to create a response document for a main document which is the order document. there is a product document which display the view of all product in the database and with a checkbox, both document are on one page. using the below code on the onclick event if the checkbox

```
var colName = view1Collection.getColumnValue("Name");
var prodNameScope = sessionScope.get("scopeProdName");
var docIdScope = sessionScope.get("scopeDocID");

var selDocID = view1Collection.getUniversalID();

 if(docIdScope .contains(selDocID )) {
    prodNameScope .remove(colName );
    docIdScope .remove(selDocID );
    } else {
    prodNameScope .add(colName );
    docIdScope .add(selDocID );
}
```

Postopen event:

```
var nameList = new java.util.ArrayList();
sessionScope.put('scopeProdName', nameList );
var idList = new java.util.ArrayList();
sessionScope.put('scopeDocID', idList );
```

On the next pages the item displayed well, but i want the selected item to be copied and save  as a response document to the main document.

i have tried the below script but did not work:

```
var PN = sessionScope.get("scopeProdName[indexRowdata]");
document1.replaceItemValue("_Title", PN);
```

anyone have idea how i could go about this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you display the articles in a view control you can get the id:s of then using

```
 var myArray = sessionScope.get("projectName");
 var PNu = sessionScope.get("projectNumber");

 document1.replaceItemValue("ProjectName", myArray);
 document1.replaceItemValue("ProjectNumber", PNu);

 var PN:java.util.ArrayList = sessionScope.get("scopeProdName");

 document1.save()
 var Id:java.util.ArrayList=sessionScope.get("scopeDocID");

 for(var x=0;x<Id.size();x++){
   var doc=database.getDocumentByUNID(Id.get(x)); 
   var newdoc:NotesDocument=doc.copyToDatabase(database);
   newdoc.makeResponse(document1.getDocument());
   newdoc.save();
 }
```

Comment: i display the articles using dataTable, after geting the sellected to the preview page, i use a dataTable to display the sellected item computing: `scopeProdName[indexRowdata]`  now i need preview articles in the dataTable to be save as response document to document1

Comment: If you fetch all the selected ID:s into an JS Array Use the loop to copy them and make them responses.

Comment: that is the issue i dont get the code to do that i keep getting error i dont know what am missing out, fetching the sellected IDs from the Js Array. what is the right code to use?

Comment: I have updated my code in the answer. You need to do a .get with the index number

Comment: i really appreciat your assistance so far, but i keep getting the error indexRowdata not found, i dont mind if i could send u the nsf file for u to see.

Comment: Sure send the nsf to me fredrik at xpagedeveloper.com and I will take a look